# Kdenlive Background Color

Tags: kdenlive

How do I change the background color in Kdenlive from black to white?

I have a png image (or svg or gif - doesn't matter) with a transparent background. I make a new Kdenlive video. I add the image. The transparent area of the image is rendered as black. I want it rendered as white.

I've been searching and everything I find is about setting chroma keys to do weatherman-like effects and stuff like that. All that I want to do is find WHERE is the setting that says "If there is no color, use white, not black."

I know that I could open the image and replace the transparency with white. That is not the point. This is not the actual job I'm trying to do. The job I'm trying to do is at a standstill because Kdenlive forces missing colors to be black and I want them to be white. But, I cannot find the setting. I cannot find the documentation on it. I cannot find any web page post where anyone else in history has tried to do this. Everyone is trying to do green or blue transparency effects. I have absolutely no interest in that.

Comment: I have found a work-around that is almost functional. I can add a color clip, choosing white. I can place that behind the images, giving them a white background. I have to manually drag the length of the clip to make it cover the length of the video. I don't see a way to say "This is ALWAYS in the background at all times."

Comment: That's how I have always done it, using dummy clips just to get a background color. I'm not aware of any alternative.